# how to run Boot Broadcast Receiver on android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

i am actually working on alarm app that set alarm ans store alarm data into room database,i want to Re Schedule my alarms after the phone reboot.
all work fine but its not working on android 11.In android 11 the boot reciver not trigger and in other devices boot receiver trigger and set all the alarm stored  in database

thanks

i am using this code

```
 override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED == intent?.action)
    {
        

    }
}
```

Comment: You have an empty if statement? I am wonderring how is that working on other decices...

Comment: brother i just post my general logic...in my if statement i show a logcat...for testing

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In Android 11 you need to open your app after restarting to receive Boot_Complete_receiver

Comment: Any link to documentation about this? This requirement makes the broadcast completely useless, right?

Comment: why this answer have right mark, it doesn't makes sense

Comment: This is not true. It makes broadcast receiver useless

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have set the below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and added the intent filter for your receiver like below

```
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
```

If the above things are in place. Then try the below things as well

1. Click on the app after installing your app as until your app is enabled you won't be able to receive BOOT COMPLETE action
2. Check the condition like below

   if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()))

Comment: brother all tried but not working with android 11 ...all other android versions work fine

Comment: @HannanShahid Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699244/boot-completed-not-working-on-android-10-q-api-level-29